# C++ Question about linker and multiple class declarations

Tags: c++

So I have a file called test.cpp

```
class Entity
{
    int c = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int d = 5;

};
```

And then another called main.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
class Entity
{

    int a = 5;
    int b = 0;


};
int main()
{
    
}
```

Why does this link and work just fine? Doesn't the linker see that there are 2 classes with the same name and different data members? Also would these be considered class definitions? If I wanna declare this class in a header file I would just do what I did here right? Even though I'm technically defining variables it's still just a class declaration right..?

Comment: Classes don't really exists once the compiler has passed the translation units to the linker, only objects.

Comment: On the other hand, since you have different definitions of the class in different translation units, your program will have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: So these are considered definitions I guess but if I wanna create the class  from test.cpp in a header file how would I declare it exactly?

Comment: Move the full definition from the source file to the header file. Delete the definition in all source files. Include the header file.

Comment: But is it okay to actually give class data members values in a declaration? Because I feel like if I'm doing that then it just becomes a definition like if I have a class 
class E
{
int a = 0;
};
and just put this in a header file this is a definition right?

Comment: Inline initialization of members have been valid since the C++11 standard.

Comment: And you're not only declaring the class, you're *defining* it as well. A class declaration would be like `class Entity;`

Answer (score 1):

It is an ill-formed program.

As the class definition has external linkage then each definition of the class  shall consist of the same sequence of tokens.

On the other hand, as neither code from the translation unit test.cpp is used the linker can exclude it from the final exe file.